# PC won't turn on after changing CMOS

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, uefi, desktop-computer

I changed my CMOS battery and when I tried to turn on, after showing this screen below, the monitor goes blank.

[image: Initial Screen]

And I can't press F10 or DEL to enter bios either, as only after this screen would it display that message at bottom saying press this key to enter bios.

I tried changing sata cable to different port, and now it's showing the below message.

[image: Initial Screen after changing sata port]

But still blank screen and wouldn't proceed further.

And it didn't even turn on yesterday and when I tried again today morning, it turns on but still the blank screen.

Motherboard: P8H77-MPRO
CPU: i7-3770k
I think got this system in 2013.

Sample BIOS image of this MB which I took from internet.
[image: BIOS screen sample]

Comment: IDE mode is typically not compatible with newer storage devices. Your BIOS/UEFI settings likely were reset.

Comment: Try disconnecting all drives, then going into the BIOS and fixing those settings.

Comment: @Ramhound Ya I guess. But after that screen, it goes blank. I couldn't enter BIOS.

Comment: @MiG okay, let me try this.

Comment: @MiG I disconnected all disk drives, still getting blank screen after seeing what is in first image.

Comment: And the other way around? Do you have an old PATA drive lying around that you could temporarily hook up?

Comment: @MiG you mean HDD? I have a 2TB HDD connected to pc, it doesn't have OS

Comment: What bothers me is, why I cant open BIOS, this MB has UEFI BIOS.

Comment: @GowthamRajJ - Are you sure? 2013 is awfully old (almost a decade).

Comment: PATA (parallel ATA) is the backronym currently used for oldfashioned ATA drives.

Comment: @Ramhound https://ibb.co/r7QYcMD is a screenshot of a youtube video showing the bios screen.

Comment: @Ramhound edited answer to add image inline.